# Mapping issue Spring Model class automatic generating column and returned null as column value

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

here are my mysql table named employee definition

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `EmployeeId` int NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReportsTo` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `BirthDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `HireDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(70) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PostalCode` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(24) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fax` varchar(24) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeeId`),
  KEY `IFK_EmployeeReportsTo` (`ReportsTo`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EmployeeReportsTo` FOREIGN KEY (`ReportsTo`) REFERENCES `employee` (`EmployeeId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

here is my model class

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Data
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee_Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "EmployeeId")
    Integer id;

    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    String FirstName;

    @Column(name = "LastName")
    String LastName;

    @Column(name = "Title")
    String Title;

    @Column(name = "ReportsTo")
    Integer ReportsTo;

    @Column(name = "BirthDate")
    LocalDateTime BirthDate;

    @Column(name = "HireDate")
    LocalDateTime HireDate;

    @Column(name = "Address")
    String Address;

    @Column(name = "City")
    String City;
    @Column(name = "State")
    String State;
    @Column(name = "Country")
    String Country;

    @Column(name = "PostalCode")
    String PostalCode;
    @Column(name = "Phone")
    String Phone;
    @Column(name = "Fax")
    String Fax;
    @Column(name = "Email")
    String Email;
}
```

when i hit endpoint it gives me below output

```
 {
        "id": 0,
        "state": "AB",
        "address": "11120 Jasper Ave NW",
        "country": "Canada",
        "lastName": null,
        "firstName": null,
        "city": "Edmonton",
        "postalCode": null,
        "phone": "+1 (780) 428-9482",
        "fax": "+1 (780) 428-3457",
        "email": "andrew@chinookcorp.com",
        "reportsTo": null,
        "title": "General Manager",
        "birthDate": null,
        "hireDate": null
    }
```

I could not understand why it gives me null in certain fields although data is avallible in database and also change databse table structure like below

```
CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `EmployeeId` int NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReportsTo` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `BirthDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `HireDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(70) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `PostalCode` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(24) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fax` varchar(24) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_id` int NOT NULL,
  `birth_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hire_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postal_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reports_to` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeeId`),
  KEY `IFK_EmployeeReportsTo` (`ReportsTo`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EmployeeReportsTo` FOREIGN KEY (`ReportsTo`) REFERENCES `employee` (`EmployeeId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

but when i change the value of name attribute of @Column annotation of the fields that gives me null to the lowercase letter it is working fine like this

@Column(name = "birthdate")
LocalDateTime BirthDate;

@Column(name = "FirstName")
String FirstName;

can you explain me how it is working?

**how hibernte naming strategie working ?**
**why it is giving me null values in certin fields?**
**if i change those column name to lower case why it is working fine?**